# 2D interpolation

Tags: interpolation

Consider following series of functions

```
 Do[f[k][w_] = Exp[-(w-Sin[k])^2], {k, 10}]
```

depicted as

[image: series of dunctions]

Let us tabulate and interpolate them

```
fdata = Flatten[Table[{w, k, f[k][w]}, {w, -3, 3, 0.1}, {k, 10}], 1];
g = Interpolation[fdata];
```

Instead of a smooth function some irregularities appear:

```
ListPlot3D[fdata]
```

as shown here

[image: 3d image]

Let us zoom in

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[{g[w, 1], g[w, 1.5], g[w, 2]}], {w, -2, 3},
 PlotStyle -> {Black,Red,Black},Axes -> False,Frame->True]
```

The red curve should look similar to 2 black ones and have a peak somewhere in the middle. Instead, due to the 2d interpolation a much larger peak at wrong location arises.

[image: 3 curves]

My question therefore would be: is there a way to do such interpolation in mathematica properly?

Comment: But ... you never really use the interpolation in your 3D plot

Comment: @Sektor Indeed, my problem is interpolation, not the 3d plot itself. I am aware of the fact that ListPlot3D performs interpolation as well. If I have a good original function I would be able to get rid of plot-induced features by using a finer mesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we dont know the underlying function, start with a 1D interpolation of each curve:

```
Do[ intf[k] = Interpolation[Table[{x, f[k][x]}, {x, -3, 3, .1}]] , {k,10}];
```

find the 'shift' from one curve to the next, assuming they are similar
( this is very slow )

```
diff[a_?NumericQ, i_, j_] := 
 NIntegrate[(intf[i][x] - intf[j][x + a])^2 , {x, -2, 2}]
offsets = Table[a /. Last@NMinimize[diff[a, i, i + 1]], {i, 9} ]
```

> {0.0678265, -0.768177, -0.897923, -0.202122, 0.679509, 0.936402, 0.332372,-.57724, -0.95614}

now construct a 2d interpolation by linearly interpolating between the 1d interpolation functions:

```
intf2d[y_?NumericQ, x_] := 
 Module[ {k = Floor[y], ci = FractionalPart[y]},
      (1 - ci) intf[k][x - ci offsets[[k]]] + 
       ci  intf[k + 1][x + (1 - ci) offsets[[k]]]]
```

now we can let `Plot3D` sample it as needed to make a reasonably smooth plot

```
Plot3D[ intf2d[k, x], {k, 1, 10}, {x, -3, 3},PlotPoints->100]
```

[image]

superpose the original curves for validation:

```
Show[ 
  { Plot3D[intf2d[k, x], {k, 1, 10}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotPoints->100] , 
     Graphics3D[Table[{Thick, Green,
       Line[Table[{k, x, f[k][x]}, {x, -3, 3, .1}]]}, {k, 1, 10}]]}]
```

[image]

You could probably improve on this by fitting a smooth curve through the `offsets`.

Comment: Aha, so in other words you are suggesting to apply some linear transformation (shift) before doing interpolation. Maybe not perfect, but already something.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is the result of [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation). Here is a simple 1D example [taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#/media/File:Interpolation_example_polynomial.svg)

[image]

Notice specifically that the curve between points $1$ and $2$, as well as between $4$ and $5$ isn't actually between those samples. Still, this seems to be a better fit of the data, even though it's not an optimal local interpolation. The reason to use polynomial interpolation is to improve the smoothness of the overall fit.

If your main concern is that you get a straight, linear interpolation between the individual curves, and don't care about smoothness, then you should tell `Interpolate` to do so, by setting the `InterpolationOrder` parameter to `1` (the default is `3`):

```
Do[f[k][w_] = Exp[-(w - Sin[k])^2], {k, 10}]
fdata = Flatten[Table[{w, k, f[k][w]}, {w, -3, 3, 0.1}, {k, 10}], 1];
g = Interpolation[fdata, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Plot[Evaluate[{g[w, 1], g[w, 1.5], g[w, 2]}], {w, -2, 3},
```

PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Black}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]

[image]

Also note that the 3rd-order interpolation of `Interpolate` is actually smoother than the samples displayed by `ListPlot3D`:

```
g = Interpolation[fdata];
Plot3D[Evaluate[g[w, k]], {w, -3, 3}, {k, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

So it really depends on what you're looking for. If you want a smooth interpolation, there are bound to be adjacent samples where not every interpolated curve lies exactly between. If you want to ensure that, you'll have to use linear interpolation, but then your surface won't be smooth.

Comment: I actually want both, a smooth interpolation with interpolated curve in between based on a priory knowledge that the shape of all functions in the series is similar, but the curves may be shifted.

Comment: @yarchik I don't think that is going to happen with `Interpolation`. (And in fact, if you fit the correct solution, i.e. a sine wave through your samples you will notice that even the correct solution, at its extrema, will not always lie between the two adjacent samples.) I don't know what other what other interpolation functions Mathematica provides, but if that's not what you're looking for you might have to roll your own.

Comment: Something like a [smoothstep interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) might work (it'll be smooth and always between two adjacent samples), although I think the resulting fit would look a lot worse than the polynomial interpolation you already have.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put more points in between to get what you want:

```
i = 1; Do[(f[i++][w_] = Exp[-(w - Sin[k])^2]), {k, 1, 10, .1}]
fdata = Table[{w, k, f[k][w]}, {w, -3, 3, 0.1}, {k, i}];
ListPlot3D[Flatten[fdata, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This actually defeats the purpose of my example. For real world case it is overshoot and inefficient to use so many points.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a comment (with code) that hopefully illuminates the problem.

This demonstrates that ad-hoc connection into polygons of the points generated regularly over the curves brings a result similar to that of `ListPlot3D`:

```
Block[{fdata = fdata},
 fdata = SortBy[#, #[[1]] &] & /@ 
   SortBy[GatherBy[fdata, #[[2]] &], #[[All, 2]] &];
 ps = Map[
   Function[{rpair}, 
    MapThread[Polygon[Join[#1, #2]] &, 
     Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ rpair]], Partition[fdata, 2, 1]];
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Black], ps}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Would you then say (based on your plot) that linear interpolation is superior for such functions?

Comment: @yarchik Hmm... No. I would say linear interpolation is *also* inadequate. I was considering giving an answer similar to [that of george2029](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110299/34008).

Comment: @yarchik I see the code and plot I put as a way to explain the results from `ListPlot3D`. If we compare the plots there are obvious similarities.

Comment: yes, indeed, there are similarities. I think a lot can be done along the lines suggested by @george2079, but it is probably not easy to find a general solution.